# TBB: How can I measure scheduling overhead?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I have a very simple `parallel_for` loop that does some work on a large vector. While this is a contrived example, I am hoping to measure any potential overhead with scheduling by varying grain size. The loop is as follows:

```
    tbb_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, values.size(), grainSize),
    [&](tbb::blocked_range<int> r)
    {
        for (int i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); ++i)
        {
            values[i] = std::sin(i * 0.001);
        }
    });
   tbb_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   loop_duration = (tbb_end - tbb_start);

   std::cout << "TBB Time: " << loop_duration.count() << "ms" << std::endl;
```

My assumption here is that increasing the grain size will reduce the scheduling overhead (since more work will be done by fewer threads). How then to measure this change in overhead? Per this paper:

https://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/sites/default/files/PDF/ewomp99paper.pdf

The authors take the difference between the parallel run time and serial run time, divide that by the number of processors and that number will be the overhead. Is this the standard way to do it? Is there another (possibly better) way?

Comment: I usually go about it like this: How quickly do I get the result to where I need it to be? Can I do better? Theory is good, but real measurements are key.

Comment: Rule of thumb body should be [at least 10000 clock cycles](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Design_Patterns/Agglomeration.html)
Also picking some specific [scheduler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/604706) could change performance

Comment: May be you could measure time of each body run to different places in memory to avoid false sharing by thread id. But it also has enough flaws)